# Simpler way to traverse complex dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am iterating over a complex json object loaded as a dictionary into python.  Below is a sample of the json file.  The data of interest is commented.

```
{  
   "name":"ns1:timeSeriesResponseType",
   "nil":false,
   "value":{  
      "queryInfo":{  },
      "timeSeries":[  
         {  
            "variable":{  },
            "values":[  
               {  
                  "qualifier":[  ],
                  "censorCode":[  ],
                  "value":[  
                     {  
                        "codedVocabularyTerm":null,
                        "censorCode":null,
                        "offsetTypeID":null,
                        "accuracyStdDev":null,
                        "timeOffset":null,
                        "qualifiers":[  
                           "P",                      # data of interest
                           "Ice"                     # data of interest
                        ],
                        "qualityControlLevelCode":null,
                        "sampleID":null,
                        "dateTimeAccuracyCd":null,
                        "methodCode":null,
                        "codedVocabulary":null,
                        "sourceID":null,
                        "oid":null,
                        "dateTimeUTC":null,
                        "offsetValue":null,
                        "metadataTime":null,
                        "labSampleCode":null,
                        "methodID":null,
                        "value":"-999999",
                        "dateTime":"2015-02-24T03:30:00.000-05:00",
                        "offsetTypeCode":null,
                        "sourceCode":null
                     },
                     {  
                        "codedVocabularyTerm":null,
                        "censorCode":null,
                        "offsetTypeID":null,
                        "accuracyStdDev":null,
                        "timeOffset":null,
                        "qualifiers":[  ],
                        "qualityControlLevelCode":null,
                        "sampleID":null,
                        "dateTimeAccuracyCd":null,
                        "methodCode":null,
                        "codedVocabulary":null,
                        "sourceID":null,
                        "oid":null,
                        "dateTimeUTC":null,
                        "offsetValue":null,
                        "metadataTime":null,
                        "labSampleCode":null,
                        "methodID":null,
                        "value":"-999999",                          # data of interest
                        "dateTime":"2015-02-24T04:00:00.000-05:00", # data of interest
                        "offsetTypeCode":null,
                        "sourceCode":null
                     }
                  ],
                  "sample":[  ],
                  "source":[  ],
                  "offset":[  ],
                  "units":null,
                  "qualityControlLevel":[  ],
                  "method":[  ]
               }
            ],
            "sourceInfo":{  },
            "name":"USGS:03193000:00060:00011"
         },
         {  },  # more data need is stored in here
         {  },  # more data need is stored in here
         {  }   # more data need is stored in here
      ]
   },
   "declaredType":"org.cuahsi.waterml.TimeSeriesResponseType",
   "scope":"javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement$GlobalScope",
   "globalScope":true,
   "typeSubstituted":false
}
```

And here is my code for stepping through/iterating over the dictionary to get to the data I want and store it in a more simply formatted dictionary:

```
# Setting up blank variables to store results
outputDict = {}
outputList = []
dateTimeList = []
valueList = []
qualifiersList = [[]]


for key in result["value"]["timeSeries"]:
    for key2 in key:
        if key2 == "values":
            for key3 in key.get(key2):
                for key4 in key3:
                    if key4 == "value":
                        for key5 in key3.get(key4):
                            for key6 in key5:
                                if key6 == "value":
                                    valueList.append(key5.get(key6))
                                if key6 == "dateTime":
                                    dateTimeList.append(key5.get(key6))
                        #print key.get("name")
                        #outputDict[key.get("name")]["dateTime"] = dateTimeList
                        #outputDict[key.get("name")]["values"] = valueList

        if key2 == "name":
            outputList.append(key.get(key2))
            outputDict[key.get(key2)]={"dateTime":None, "values":None, "qualifiers":None}
            outputDict[key.get("name")]["dateTime"] = dateTimeList
            outputDict[key.get("name")]["values"] = valueList
            del dateTimeList[:]
            del valueList[:]
```

My question is this - being somewhat new to python, can anyone point any obvious inefficiencies in my code?  I can count on the json file not changing structure for a couple of months - possibly years - and so I believe that my initial use of the *for key in result["value"]["timeSeries"]:* is fine, but I'm not sure if the many, many for loops are unnecessary or inefficient.  Is there a simple way to search out and return key:value pairs from such a hierarchical dictionary, with lists of dictionaries inside lists of dictionaries?

**EDIT:**

Based on the solution provided by @Alex Martelli, here the new, more efficient, trimmed version of the code:

```
# Building the output dictionary
for key in result["value"]["timeSeries"]:
    if "values" in key:
        for key2 in key.get("values"):
            if "value" in key2:
                for key3 in key2.get("value"):
                    if "value" in key3:
                        valueList.append(key3.get("value"))
                    if "dateTime" in key3:
                        dateTimeList.append(key3.get("dateTime"))
                    if "qualifiers" in key3:
                        qualifiersList.append(key3.get("qualifiers"))

    if "name" in key:
        outputList.append(key.get("name"))
        outputDict[key.get("name")]={"dateTime":None, "values":None, "qualifiers":None}
        outputDict[key.get("name")]["dateTime"] = dateTimeList[:]    # passing the items in the list rather
        outputDict[key.get("name")]["values"] = valueList[:]         # than a reference to the list so the delete works
        outputDict[key.get("name")]["qualifiers"] = qualifiersList[:]         # than a reference to the list so the delete works
        del dateTimeList[:]
        del valueList[:]
        del qualifiersList[:]
```

Works the same, removed 4 lines of code.   Faster run time.  Nice.

**EDIT:**

Based on the solution proposed by @Two-Bit Alchemist, this works as well:

```
# Building the output dictionary
    for key in result["value"]["timeSeries"]:
        print key
        for value in key["values"][0]["value"]:
            # qualifiers is a list containing ["P", "Ice"]
            qualifiersList.append(value['qualifiers'])
            valueList.append(value['value'])
            dateTimeList.append(value['dateTime'])


        if "name" in key:
            outputList.append(key.get("name"))
            outputDict[key.get("name")]={"dateTime":None, "values":None, "qualifiers":None}
            outputDict[key.get("name")]["dateTime"] = dateTimeList[:]    # passing the items in the list rather
            outputDict[key.get("name")]["values"] = valueList[:]         # than a reference to the list so the delete works
            outputDict[key.get("name")]["qualifiers"] = qualifiersList[:]         # than a reference to the list so the delete works
            del dateTimeList[:]
            del valueList[:]
            del qualifiersList[:]
```

The only problem I see is that I'm never fully sure that the 1st location in the ["values"] list is what I want.  And I lose the checks provided by the "if" statements, checks that should ensure errors aren't introduced if values are returned from faulty query statements.

**EDIT:**

```
try:

    # requests.get returns a "file-like" object
    # in this case it is a JSON object because of the settings in the query
    response = requests.get(url=query)


    # if-else ladder that only performs the parsing of the returned JSON object
    # when the HTTP status code indicates a successful query execution
    if(response.status_code == 200):

        # parsing the
        result = response.json()

        # Setting up blank variables to store results
        outputDict = {}
        outputList = []
        dateTimeList = []
        valueList = []
        qualifiersList = []


        # Building the output dictionary
        for key in result["value"]["timeSeries"]:
            print key
            for value in key["values"][0]["value"]:
                # qualifiers is a list containing ["P", "Ice"]
                qualifiersList.append(value['qualifiers'])
                valueList.append(value['value'])
                dateTimeList.append(value['dateTime'])

            # OLD CODE   
            # if "values" in key:
            #     for key2 in key.get("values"):
            #         if "value" in key2:
            #             for key3 in key2.get("value"):
            #                 if "value" in key3:
            #                     valueList.append(key3.get("value"))
            #                 if "dateTime" in key3:
            #                     dateTimeList.append(key3.get("dateTime"))
            #                 if "qualifiers" in key3:
            #                     qualifiersList.append(key3.get("qualifiers"))

            if "name" in key:
                outputList.append(key.get("name"))
                outputDict[key.get("name")]={"dateTime":None, "values":None, "qualifiers":None}
                outputDict[key.get("name")]["dateTime"] = dateTimeList[:]    # passing the items in the list rather
                outputDict[key.get("name")]["values"] = valueList[:]         # than a reference to the list so the delete works
                outputDict[key.get("name")]["qualifiers"] = qualifiersList[:]         # than a reference to the list so the delete works
                del dateTimeList[:]
                del valueList[:]
                del qualifiersList[:]


        # Tracking how long it took to process the data
        elapsed = time.time() - now
        print "Runtime: " + str(elapsed)

        out = {"Status": 'ok', "Results": [[{"myResult": outputDict}]]}

    elif(response.status_code == 400):
        raise Exception("Bad Request, "+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif(response.status_code== 403):
        raise Exception("Access Forbidden, "+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif(response.status_code == 404):
        raise Exception("Gage location(s) not Found, "+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif(response.status_code == 500):
        raise Exception("Internal Server Error, "+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif(response.status_code == 503):
        raise Exception("Service Unavailable, "+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown Response, "+ datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))



except:
    out = {"Status": 'Error', "Message": str(sys.exc_info()[1])}


print out
```

Comment: I think you just need to access it, right? Something like `dct['value']['timeSeries'][0]['values'][0]['value'][0]['qualifiers']` if `dct` is your json structure. That might not be exactly right because, yes, that thing is extremely complicated!

Comment: So, that would work if I know how many responses to my query there might be.  But, at any one time there might be 1 to dozens of responses, and I don't exactly know how many responses and so I don't know how many i's to place (or loop over) in your solution.  If I always knew the total number of responses, your suggestion would work.  But I'm not sure if it can otherwise.

Comment: What part of that structure are you calling a "response" that there is a variable number of?

Comment: Ahh, yes - I'm not being clear enough.  The whole structure - the json object loaded into the python dictionary - is a response to a query to a web service.  The internal two main parts "timeSeries"(which contains all the data I am interested in) and "queryInfo" (which I'm not interested in) will grow based on the specific attributes of the query I'm executing against the web service.  I need to write this code to handle queries that could return a list with 1 to dozens of members in the list of dictionaries under "timeSeries".

Comment: I am still confused why this question cannot be solved with **one for loop** -- and I freely admit I  may still be misunderstanding the question. Something like `for data in json_structure['value']['timeSeries']: data['values'][0]['value'][0]['qualifiers'] # etc` -- if the list stored at `timeSeries` has some unknown length, just **iterate over it** and repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask "any obvious inefficiencies in my code" -- the answer is yes, specifically where you're looping over dictionaries (thus getting all their keys sequentially, which is `O(N)`, i.e, takes a time proportional to the number of keys in the dictionary) rather than just using them as dictionaries (which takes time `O(1)`, i.e, constant time -- fast too).

So for example where you have

```
for key2 in key:
    if key2 == "values":
       ...use key.get(key2)...
    if key2 == "name":
       ...use key.get(key2)...
```

you should instead have:

```
if 'values' in key:
   ...use key['values']...
if 'name' in key:
   ...use key['name']...
```

and similar constructs deeper in.  Things can be optimized further, e.g with:

```
values = key.get('values')
if values is not None:
    ...use values...
name = key.get('name')
if name is not None:
    ...use name...
```

to avoid repeating the indexing (again, similarly deeper in).

Comment: Thanks!  I don't quite understand yet, but I will work on it!

Comment: The `in` operator, when the RHS is a dictionary, return true if the LHS is a key in that dictionary.  The `get` method of a dictionary returns `None` when called with an argument that's **not** a key in that dictionary.  That's about all there is to it!  BTW, remember to eventually **accept** the answer, i.e, click on the checkmark outline to the left of it... unless you get a better one which seems unlikely by now:-)

Comment: About to post my implementation - look forward to seeing if I missed any gains in efficiency.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @traggatmot, you're welcome -- if you post it as a separate Q you'll no doubt get answers pinpointing any further good optimizations!

Comment: @AlexMartelli I think a lot of OP's code is caused by a kind of wide-eyed reaction to an admittedly complex data structure, and a misunderstanding of access/EAFP. This can be done quite a bit more simply. (See my answer and update.)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this question, I believe your initial perplexing approach to the problem, which is massively overkill, has clouded a very simple solution. Please correct me if I am still misunderstanding this and oversimplifying. Even though this structure is very complicated, if the variable part of it is the length of the list at `timeSeries`, you can just access that list and iterate over it while repeatedly grabbing your "data of interest". I don't know what this data is to give you a good example data structure or even decent variable names for how it should be stored to be used later in your program, so I'm just going to store it in a big list of lists just to show you how I mean:

```
data_of_interest = []
for data in json_structure['value']['timeSeries']:
    value_list = data['values'][0]['value']
    # qualifiers is a list containing ["P", "Ice"]
    qualifiers = value_list[0]['qualifiers']
    value = value_list[1]['value']
    dateTime = value_list[1]['dateTime']
    data_of_interest.append([qualifiers, value, dateTime])
```

If there are repetitions at other places where I have hard-coded the index 0, **just introduce for loops there**, e.g.

```
for data in json_structure['value']['timeSeries']:
    for value_set in data['values']:
        for value_list in value_set['value']:
            # etc
```

---

If you are worried about some values not being there, just be prepared to catch a `KeyError` from the dict or equivalent.

For example, where I write:

```
value = value_list[1]['value']
```

This could raise an `IndexError` if `value_list` does not have >= 2 values, or a `KeyError` if its second element is not a dict mapping 'value' to something. You can catch one or both of these, and handle them together or separately, or just ignore them and keep going.

```
try:
    value = value_list[1]['value']
except KeyError:    # catch only one
    # do something
```

or

```
try:
    value = value_list[1]['value']
except (IndexError, KeyError):    # catch both
    # handle together
```

or

```
try:
    value = value_list[1]['value']
except IndexError:
    # handle IndexError
except KeyError:
    # handle KeyError
```

and your `# handle whatever` code may well be `pass` -- which just means "I know this might happen, but don't freak out. Just keep reading." If you *don't* catch them, the exceptions will "bubble up" to the top of the execution context and crash your program.

Comment: Updated the question to show the implementation of your solution - I still worry about it, as it loses the checks provided by the if-statements.  I believe, though I am not perfectly sure, that these if-statements should prevent failure of the code when the query result doesn't contain the expected values.

Comment: The great thing about dictionaries is that they will raise a `KeyError` in case those values are not present. So just surround your accesses with try/except and catch this. I will update my answer.

Comment: Incidentally guarding with if statements is called "Look Before You Leap" or LBYL, whereas using try/except as I am showing you is called "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" or EAFP. The latter is preferred in Python, as it has advantages in, e.g., multi-threaded environments.

Comment: I already have this code catch in try/catch statements. I'll post the whole code.

Comment: I need to figure out how to pass those KeyErrors you are talking about to the larger try/catch.

Comment: You don't pass exceptions around, you just catch them or not. If you want something higher up to catch it, then don't catch it and let it do its job. Also, wrapping your whole code in try/except is very pointless and never recommended. Your code will just print a stack trace if it hits an unhandled exception -- that's what Python does anyway!